# RegEx LookBehind for more than one char?

Tags: java, regex, lookbehind

Is there a way in Java, when you use a RegEx look-behind to look for more than 1 character behind? I have this:

```
return str.replaceAll(".(?<!" + word + ")", "+");
```

With what I can replace the "?" in the RegEx to get the lookbehind for more than 1 char? Say 2 or 3 chars.

Comment: The regex you have should work, the "?" in this case doesn't mean "one character"

Comment: I've just noticed you have a dot before your negative-look-behind, What are you trying to do?

Comment: @morgano isn't ? for 0 or 1 char? Or I am wrong? I try to leave it unchanged so like:
`Input str = "12xy45" word = "xy" Output "++xy++"`